# matrix equation PAQ=B with know A,B; determine full rank P, Q

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I think I'm stuck in an odd question. Here's it

[image]

I think the answer should be unique since the question requires full rank matrix. Otherwise it will be simple as matrix left/right multiplication is basically linear combination of rows and columns, I guess there are many combinations can achieve the RHS. I don't even know how to start. can you guys please give me some hint to solve the question. Thanks very much!

Comment: What is the dimension of $Ker(A_0)$ ? and of $Ker(B)$, where $B$ is the last matrix ?

Comment: @Kelenner I am really curious how to solve this as well, could you provide more hints?

Comment: Somehow I think I was tricked by the question. If P and Q are both invertible, then rank(A) =rank(PAQ) = rank(B) or say dim Ker(A) = dim Ker (B). But clearly it is not the case. the rank of A is 2 and the rank of B is 1. So I guess the answer to the question is just impossible. P, Q should not exist.